# how do i get the [response_data:protected] from my return object , i tried some object to array conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway

here my return object as follow

```
 QuickPay\API\Response Object
 (

    [response_data:protected] => {"id":35979283,"merchant_id":20944,"order_id":"14752117819630","accepted":false,"type":"Payment","text_on_statement":null,"branding_id":null,"variables":{},"currency":"DKK","state":"initial","metadata":{"type":null,"origin":null,"brand":null,"bin":null,"last4":null,"exp_month":null,"exp_year":null,"country":null,"is_3d_secure":null,"hash":null,"number":null,"customer_ip":null,"customer_country":null,"fraud_suspected":false,"fraud_remarks":[],"nin_number":null,"nin_country_code":null,"nin_gender":null},"link":null,"shipping_address":null,"invoice_address":{"name":"Vivek U","att":null,"street":null,"city":null,"zip_code":null,"region":null,"country_code":null,"vat_no":null,"house_number":null,"house_extension":null,"phone_number":"12345","mobile_number":"12345","email":"amit.chauhan@dignizant.com"},"basket":[],"shipping":null,"operations":[],"test_mode":false,"acquirer":null,"facilitator":null,"created_at":"2016-09-30T05:02:57Z","balance":0,"fee":null}
 )
```

Please anything help i will appreciate it

Comment: try a getter method.

Comment: means can you explain it ?

Comment: i am new to accessing objects

Comment: Where does the Response class come from? Can you possibly show its code?

Comment: a quick pay class

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124610/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-rax-weber).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `print_r($payments->asArray());`.

Comment: thanks its works , i really appreciated of your answer